# How to get Symfony session variable in model?

Tags: symfony1, session-variables

How can I pass session variable in symfony model without using `sfContext::getInstance()`?

Comment: some more information would be welcome? What kind of "session" variable do you need in your model? Where is it created/assigned, where is it needed, etc. Because, usually it's a sign of a bad model when you need `sfContext::getInstance()` in your model, just like you said.

Comment: what do you want to do? If you want to keep some values during a session you can add them as attributes to the user, for example

Comment: Are you looking for a backend application created with the admin generator?

Comment: Hi Grad... as mentioned am using setAttribute for userid in lib class...i need to access the session in model class within save method ...but i kno sfContext::getInstance() is bad idea so am looking for alternate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is called dependency injection, and works like this: you create a `setUser()` method in your model file, that saves the given parameter to a private property:

```
class Foo {
  private $_user;

  public function setUser(myUser $user) {
    $this->_user = $user;
  }

  // ... later:

  public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null) {
    // use $this->_user to whatever you need
  }
}
```

This looks clumsy, because it is. But without you answering the question *what are you trying to do?* I cannot give an alternative.

Recommended articles:

- [What is Dependency Injection?](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection) - a post series on Fabien Potencier's blog
- [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) - the design patter in detail on wikipedia

Comment: Hi maerlyn ...as mentioned am using setAttribute for userid in lib class...i need to access the session in model class within save method ...but i kno sfContext::getInstance() is bad idea so am looking for alternate..

Comment: I understand that, and gave you an alternative. But without telling why you need the id, I cannot give a better option.

Comment: @Maerlyn: I tried that in same way. But I unable to get user id in model.$this->_user this returns empty on save function. help me out.

Comment: Are you sure you're saving the record you set the user on?

Comment: @Maerlyn: Basically i am saving contest with current logged in user id here lib/model/Contest.class.php. I am using sfdoctrineguardplugin for authentication. How can I do this.

Comment: It's been a while since I last used symfony1, but my answer should work for you, the problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

Session variables should be stored as user's attributes.

```
// in an action: 
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('current_order_id', $order_id);
```

See how to get it back.

```
// later on, in another action, you can get it as:
$order_id = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('current_order_id', false);
if($order_id!==false)
{
    // save to DB
} else {
    $this->getUser()->setFlash('error', 'Please selected an order before you can do stuff.');
    // redirect and warn the user to selected an order
    $this->redirect('orders');
}
```

Comment: This is in no way an answer to the question.

Comment: Pibeiro am not looking for the answer u gave...am asking for getting session in model class within save method without using sfContext::getInstance()...

Comment: But from where are you saving the model? You gotta save it from an action right?