# symfony user object in Model

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony1, symfony-1.4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Symfony session variable in model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340988/how-to-get-symfony-session-variable-in-model)

I need to override save() function of one of my Models. The schema requires saving user id in the dataBase. I can't seem to access the user object there. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can also define the new save function with a parameter $user

Comment: @AndreuHeineken : right but why hide this variable in Model layer? Some conceptual issue?

Comment: is hidden because is independent of the user system you use. This way you can use your model with any user system or without any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Doctrine I would create a custom behavior which adds the user id to the model.
How to do? Just look how Timestampable works.

The behavior (or my implemented Doctrine_Record_Listener) would call sfContext::getInstance()->getUser() in the preInsert() or preUpdate() hook to get the user id and set it to the model before persisting.